# I am getting HTTP response 200 for a non-existing website

Tags: php, http, curl

I am trying out the folowing piece of code:

```
<?php
$site1 = 'http://www.teraasdsfssgggdadafasfra.com.br';

$handle = curl_init($site1);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Gets the HTML or whatever is linked in the $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Gets the HTTP code */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo $httpCode;

curl_close($handle);
?>
```

As you can see, the URL is pretty strange, which would probably return a 404 code.

However, the code I get is a 200 response, as if the page existed.

I think I might be misunderstanding the criteria that should be used to check whether a page is up or not. What might I be missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: i get 0 when I run it on fake website  
and get 302 on http://www.gooogle.com

i used http://phpfiddle.org

Comment: You have to connect to a webserver to get a code. I would expect 0 for that one, however you should check `$response` for `false` to see if it failed.

Comment: I realized that when running locally, the results of my code differed from those when running on phpfiddle. Your idea, of checking whether the response was false or not, whas useful in Brad's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this in response to Abra
http://www.google.com exists
but jkshakl... will give you the 404 error you expect

```
<?php
    $site1 = "http://www.google.com/jkdshaklfjhdasf";

$handle = curl_init($site1);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Gets the HTML or whatever is linked in the $url. */
if($response = curl_exec($handle)){

/* Gets the HTTP code */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo $httpCode;

curl_close($handle); 

}

else echo "server does not exist";
?>
```

Comment: I see that we can get 3 possibilities with this code:
1) "server does not exist" - when the domain name doesn't exist or reach anywhere; 2) a positive response when it does exist; 3) 404 when a particular page on an existing server does not exist.